# Calculating correlation between intermittent events and complete data

Tags: r, correlation

In R, I have two sets of data. One shows an event every few years, such as 2002, 2007, and 2009. I then have another set of data that shows an activity count for every year, i.e. 2002, 2003...2009, 2010. Is there a way to run a correlation test in R between these two, to see if the level of activity correlates to the events?

As an example:

Legislation was passed on 2002, 2007 and 2009. We then have the count of complaints per year:

```
Year, n_complaints
2002, 100
2003, 50
2004, 75
2005, 60
2007, 120
2008, 30
2009, 75
2010, 110
```

I then want to answer the question: How does the passage of a bill correlate to the number of complaints? Is there a correlation test to answer this?

Comment: If you need help choosing a statistical test for a particular hypothesis, you should ask your question over a [stats.se] where questions about statistics are on topic. Once you know what test you want to perform, then you can ask how to do that test in R if a simple google search doesn't turn up the answer.

Comment: I'm going to give you a break because you asked for how to perform a correlation test. But, it is still difficult to tell what you want to correlate. You gave us two columns: `Year` and `n_complaints`. Are you trying to find a correlation between `Year` and `n_complaints`? Or are you trying to find a correlation between another column and `n_complaints`?

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for the correlation between n_complaints each year to the few years in which a bill was passed. I'd like to answer the question, "How does the passage of a bill affect n_complaints"?

Comment: You haven't provided a sample of which years a bill was passed.

Comment: It is in the line before the data: Legislation was passed on 2002, 2007 and 2009.

Comment: Also, I think you need to go to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ to get more information on what sort of test you can/should run like MrFlick recommended. How can you have a correlation between a binary (a bill was passed or not) and an integer. Correlation means that when one goes up a certain amount the other goes up/down by an equal proportion.

Answer (score 1):

You may find hundreds of econometric techniques (particularly in the time series literature) for answering such questions but, unfortunately, your dataset is too short to say anything certain. Let

```
df$legislation <- ifelse(df$Year %in% c(2002, 2007, 2009), 1, 0)
```

which is a typical way to define variables for such events. Again, if you had more data, you could inspect the effect of each legislation separately.

It's always a good idea to first plot the data

```
with(df, plot(x = Year, y = n_complaints, type = 'b', pch = legislation + 1))
```

[image]

where, in this case, triangles correspond to new legislations. So, one may guess that the number of complaints rises before and/or drops right after a new legislation, but that's just a guess.

It's straightforward to look at the correlation coefficient and to test its equality to zero,

```
with(df, cor.test(n_complaints, legislation))
#
#   Pearson's product-moment correlation
#
# data:  n_complaints and legislation
# t = 1.6455, df = 6, p-value = 0.151
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.2422314  0.9062091
# sample estimates:
#       cor 
# 0.5576247
```

So, the coefficient is 0.55, which would sound quite encouraging, but due to the sample size the confidence interval is vast and we cannot reject the null that actually there is no correlation.

As I said before, it surely would be interesting to look into dynamics of those time series. `ccf` corresponds to cross-correlations when we shift the time-series in time and see whether there is any correlation when leading and lagging the series.

```
ccf(df$n_complaints, df$legislation)
```

[image]

So, the correlations (lags -1, 0, and 1) show the same as the first plot: potential tendency of fewer complaints before and after new legislations. But that's without any certainty.

Lastly, the same can be seen when estimating a linear regression model. For instance,

```
summary(lm(n_complaints ~ legislation, data = df))
#
# Call:
# lm(formula = n_complaints ~ legislation, data = df)
#
# Residuals:
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -35.000 -17.083  -1.667  12.917  45.000 
#
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# (Intercept)    65.00      12.41   5.240  0.00194 **
# legislation    33.33      20.26   1.645  0.15097   
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
# Residual standard error: 27.74 on 6 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.3109,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.1961 
# F-statistic: 2.708 on 1 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.151
```

Hence, the effect of a legislation is positive, suggesting that at the same period it adds extra 33.33 complaints, with the mean being 65. However, the effect is not statistically significant. That's not surprising as there is a nice relationship between this effect and the correlation coefficient seen before.

Other things to look into would be different kinds of effects (instantaneous, permanent, or decaying). Also you should first take into account other possible factors why the correlation may be positive, because perhaps now we are seeing something spurious.

So, there is nothing really convincing that could be done with this data. Something perhaps possible in your case would be to try to obtain quarterly or monthly data for the number of complaints for the same time period.

Comment: @Adam_G, was this helpful or are you looking for a different answer?